# Create loglog plot of histogram data in xy style - python matplotlib

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have a list of values (integers) and I want to show on a graph how many times each value in it occurs.
I have created a dictionary of values and corresponding frequencies from the list as after searching on here, that seemed best way to do it

I want to plot the data out on an xy loglog graph (with connecting lines) rather than use a bar plot.

The data points on the graph appear as expected when using

```
plot.loglog(degree_frequencies.keys(),degree_frequencies.values())
```

however, since the lines on the graph connect the first key-value "co-ordinate" to the second, second to third etc and being unordered, this  creates a line that jumps about all over the place, rather than a line that goes from left to right.

Here is an example dataset - where the first "co-ordinate" pair has a higher x value than the second

```
degree_frequencies  = {8: 1, 2: 6, 3: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2}
```

(if the dictionary was rearranged to {2: 6, 3: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 8: 1} the line would look fine)

Could anyone advise the best way to go about this?  I am wondering if I need to treat the list differently in the first place or if there is in fact a way to plot data like this using matplotlib at all.

I'm a relatively inexperienced Python user, but I have spent some time trawling the internet and the documentation (which I'm finding heavy going) without finding an answer.
Easy to understand/implement (in my circumstances) would probably be more helpful than elegant yet complex solutions (if poss).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = sorted( degree_frequencies.keys( ) )
y = [ degree_frequencies[ k ] for k in x ]
plt.loglog( x, y )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response
That doesn't seem to have any effect.
I'm not sure why it should either as it isn't going to change the order in which k v dictionary pairs are passed to the graph??
I may being missing something though (or I may not have explained my difficulty clearly enough).
I've expanded original Q so hopefully makes more sense now

Comment: @Fluff sorry i misunderstood your question, i will edit my answer

Comment: Hi runnerup - 
No worries; I probably didn't word my OP very well in first place. Your updated answer works great and it also makes sense to me aswell.
Double win.
Many thanks,